# How do I strip space in the middle of output with python print

Tags: python, bash

I am trying to create a bash script with python code.

I am running this code:

```
foo = raw_input("Hostname:")
print "imonitordb.pl -dumpEntityConfig 'device:",foo, "' | grep -v serviceNOC"
```

When I run the command, I get the following output:

```
imonitordb.pl -dumpEntityConfig 'device: monk ' | grep -v serviceNOC
```

I want to get ride of the spaces by monk so it reads:

```
imonitordb.pl -dumpEntityConfig 'device:monk' | grep -v serviceNOC
```

What am I missing?

I have tried to add

```
foo1 = foo.strip()
```

but that did not help.

I feel there is something really easy I am missing, just seeing if someone has a quick answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @game0ver, this is ideal:

```
print "imonitordb.pl -dumpEntityConfig 'device:{}' | grep -v serviceNOC".format(foo)
```

As suggested by @soon in comment this will also work:

```
print "imonitordb.pl -dumpEntityConfig 'device:" + foo + "' | grep -v serviceNOC"
```

Output:

```
imonitordb.pl -dumpEntityConfig 'device:monk' | grep -v serviceNOC
```

Comment: You can use format in the end of the sentence like so: `print "imonitordb.pl -dumpEntityConfig 'device:{}' | grep -v serviceNOC".format(foo)`. Yours as is will let a space after foo

Comment: @game0ver, for the 1st answer, nope there is no space in the output. I agree format should be ideally in the end. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure, if I try with foo=what I get as output: `imonitordb.pl -dumpEntityConfig 'device:what ' | grep -v serviceNOC`